# R: Aggregate multiple columns by group in cluster/parallelized environment

Tags: r, parallel-processing, aggregate, cluster-computing

I am running a bootstrap on a large dataset with many groups and am doing this in a parallel environment. I would like to aggregate/sum each simulation by group. Here is my attempt with sample data:

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)  
clusterEvalQ(cl,library(MASS))

# create sample data
df <- data.frame(c("g1", "g1", "g1", "g2", "g2", "g2", "g2", "g2"),
                 c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                 c(9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16),
                 c(17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24))

# rename columns
colnames(df) <- c("Group", "sim1", "sim2", "sim3")

#import data into cluster
clusterExport(cl,c("df"))
output <- parSapply(cl, 1:1, function(i,...) {x <- aggregate(.~Group, df, FUN = sum)} )
stopCluster(cl)
```

I actually get the numerical result I want, but in a “list of lists” format:
["list output"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Xjt.png)

I can then take this and output to my desired output:

```
desired_output <- do.call(cbind, output)
```

As an aside, the aggregation works as intended outside of the cluster, i.e.:

```
desired_output <- aggregate(.~Group, df, FUN = sum)
```

Question: Is there a way to do this in a parallel environment that isn’t as “clunky”?

Bonus question that is more general: is there a way to run things in R in a parallel environment that allows for the full (or at least less restrained) functionality of R? I feel like I need to jerry-rig certain tasks to tailor to this environment, and the likely answer is that I'm just not sure what I'm doing.

I’m new to running a process via a cluster (and actually R in general) so if it’s blatantly obvious, forgive me.

Comment: Actually just setting `simplify=FALSE` in `parSapply` or using `parLapply` in the first place should give you the desired result, doesn't it?

Comment: It does not, unfortunately. Both approaches result in a list of 1, which is the wanted data frame.

Comment: `el(parLapply(...))`?

Comment: That works! What is that function el()? I can't find any documentation on it anywhere. EDIT: nevermind, I keep forgetting that ?function is an option. Thank you!

Comment: Yes typing `?el` reveals the mystery, it's basically the same as adding `lapply(...)[[1]]`